# Does MSDeploy require .net 4?

Tags: .net, windows, iis, msdeploy

Does MSDeploy require .net 4?

http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires .NET 2.0 Framework SP1 or greater, [look here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=F2B0FE35-15AE-4638-B72E-F96535C64591&amp%3Bdisplaylang=en#SystemRequirements).